# One-click music playlist and visuals

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for a way to immediately play a music playlist and enter full-screen visualizations with ONE-CLICK on my keyboard.

I want it to work when the application is open or closed (will open it).

By application, I mean any music player that this can be done on. And although this will probably make things a little harder... I'm running Windows 8

Any ideas?

Comment: *> with ONE-CLICK on my keyboard.*   What does that mean, is there a *one-click* button your keyboard or do you mean with a single key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been a while since I used it, but this should be possible with Winamp. `Right-click the Title bar / Options / Preferences / Plug-ins`, then check **Auto execute visualization plug-in on playback**.

Now you should be able to simply double-click or press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on an M3U or other supported playlist and have Winamp start playback and automatically launch the selected vis plugin. Check the plugin's preferences to make sure it launches in full screen using the specified resolution by default.

Comment: Thanks! I set the Auto execute visualization plugin option and configured Milkdrops plugin to load full screen. Then I used "Playlist Creator" (freeware) to create an .M3U (made sure to go into Settings -> Playlist Options -> and set to Absolute Paths to be able to open file from anywhere). Then I used "HotKeyz" to set Ctrl+Shift+Z to open the .M3U. Worked perfect!

Comment: Not to mention Winamp's Milkdrops2 plug-in has the best visualizations I've ever seen! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Ryan Geiss, the author of MilkDrop, has also written other vis plugins that you can find on [his site](http://www.geisswerks.com).